# Recreating Activity if not a lot of resources

Tags: android

I have two activities A and B. If I from activity A launch activity B then activity A is in background. Once, if I turn in to activity A, it is recreating. Activity A in method onCreate() contain code for download data from net. What is best practice existing for such situations?

Answer (score 1):

Move your downloading data routine to an `AsyncTask` which fetches the data in the background. Then write it to external storage or sqlite, etc. Your activity in `onCreate` should just query / load the data from storage.

Comment: The good idea, thank you. I was checking object Bundle on null, which passing in onCreate() method. I want to do automatic download data from net.

Answer (score 1):

As Cody Caughlan said it is best to fetch the data in the background and write it to database.

If you do not want creating activity multiple times, you can use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to avoid recreating the activity